# Не компилится программа с ассемблерной вставкой

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Происходит ошибка при компиляции программы на g++ 7.5.0

```
6asm.cpp: In function ‘int findElement(std::vector<int>&, int)’:
6asm.cpp:32:6: error: ‘asm’ operand has impossible constraints
     );
      ^
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
using namespace std;
 
int findElement(vector<int>& arr, int target) {
    int index = -1;
 
    asm volatile(
        "xor %%eax, %%eax\n"
        "mov %[arr], %%esi\n"
        "mov %[target], %%ecx\n"
        "mov $-1, %[index]\n"
        "mov $0, %%ebx\n"
 
        "search_loop:"
        "cmp %%ecx, (%%esi, %%ebx, 4)\n"
        "je found\n"
        "inc %%ebx\n"
        "cmp %%ebx, %[arrSize]\n"
        "jl search_loop\n"
        "jmp search_end\n"
 
        "found:"
        "mov %%ebx, %[index]\n"
 
        "search_end:"
 
        : [index] "+r" (index)
        : [arr] "r" (arr.data()), [target] "r" (target), [arrSize] "r" (arr.size())
        : "eax", "ebx", "ecx", "esi"
    );
 
    return index;
}
 
int main() {
    vector<int> array = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
    int target = 30;
 
    int foundIndex = findElement(array, target);
 
    if (foundIndex != -1) {
        cout << "Element " << target << " found at index " << foundIndex << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Element " << target << " not found in the array" << endl;
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

**UPD:**

Получилось скомпилить, но решает не правильно. Всегда попадает на ветку else.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
using namespace std;
 
int findElement(vector<int>& arr, int target) {
    int index = -1;
 
    asm volatile(
        "xor %%eax, %%eax\n"
        "movl %[arr], %%esi\n"
        "movl %[target], %%ecx\n"
        "movl $-1, %[index]\n"
        "movl $0, %%ebx\n"
 
        "search_loop: \n"
        "cmpl %%ecx, (%%esi, %%ebx, 4)\n"
        "je found\n"
        "incl %%ebx\n"
        "cmpl %%ebx, %[arrSize]\n"
        "jl search_loop\n"
        "jmp search_end\n"
 
        "found: \n"
        "movl %%ebx, %[index]\n"
 
        "search_end: \n"
 
        : [index] "+g" (index)
        : [arr] "r" (arr.data()), [target] "g" (target), [arrSize] "g" (arr.size())
        : "eax", "ebx", "ecx", "esi"
    );
 
    return index;
}
 
int main() {
    vector<int> array = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
    int target = 30;
 
    int foundIndex = findElement(array, target);
 
    if (foundIndex != -1) {
        cout << "Element " << target << " found at index " << foundIndex << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Element " << target << " not found in the array" << endl;
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А какой глубокий смысл в volatile при asm?

Comment: Чтобы избежать оптимизации компилятора